# Suggestions on non-linear dimensionality reduction for small, one-hot encoded dataset

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I wish to apply **non-linear dimensionality reduction** on a very small dataset (less than 100 observations). The dataset is *very sparse*, of approx 20 columns, each containing either 0 or 1. It's the result of a set of non-exclusive on-hot encoding of features. Observations are of this kind:

```
---------------------------------
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
---------------------------------
| 0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0 |
| 1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0 |
| 0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1 |

...
```

I tried with **t-SNE**, but its stochastic nature leads to very different results each time I run my code.

Any suggestions for what shall I use? I also need a technique that is *strictly non-hierarchical* (such as PCA, for example, in which each factors explains just the "leftovers" of the variance of the previous factor; I don't want that).

Comment: How about using an autoencoder to make it into a smaller dimensional latent space?

Comment: I agree, that's my main choice at the moment. My "problem" is that it's such a small and simple task I thought using Deep Learning is an overkill... I hoped I could use a quicker tool, something more `sklearn` style